# Does a resonant peak produce a distorted wave form?

Tags: resonance, frequency-response, distortion, damping-factor

**Context**

I am re-enforcing my understanding of the frequency response. From [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLCQ.png), I understand that,

> In an audio system, [the frequency response] may be used to minimize audible distortion by designing components... so that the overall response is as flat (uniform) as possible across the system's bandwidth.

I also understand that for a damped second-order system, the quality factor and the damping ratio effect the shape of the frequency response of the second-order system [2]. For example in the figure below, which is taken directly from [5], I note that as \$\zeta\$ increases, that there is an increasingly narrow peak centered around the frequency 1. In contrast to this, when \$\zeta \approx 0.5\$ (i.e., the green graph), the frequency response is fairly flat (at least below the cut off frequency).

[image]

Separately, from [3], I understand that,

> Frequency response distortion: Non-flat frequency response is a form of distortion that occurs when different frequencies are amplified by different amounts in a filter. For example, the non-uniform frequency response curve of AC-coupled cascade amplifier is an example of frequency distortion.

In [4], F.E. Anderson  writes that

> Perfect selectivity and complete freedom from distortion are incompatible in a radio receiver

All this said,  I am not 100% sure that I understand the matter fully.

**Questions**

1. True or false, is a resonant peak in the frequency response of system or component a form of distortion?
2. Why or why not?

**Bibliography**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLCQ.png) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion

[4] https://worldradiohistory.com/hd2/IDX-Site-Early-Radio/Archive-Radio-IDX/IDX/20s/Radio-1925-07-OCR-Page-0024.pdf

[5] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance

Comment: If you're trying to understand control systems, why are you reading about audio systems? The link is tenuous.

Comment: A resonance is a linear phenomenon, so all frequencies that come out of it are necessarily ones that went into it. The term "distortion" usually refers to nonlinear phenomena that create output frequencies that didn't exist in the input. But it's been too long since I did anything in this area to say much more on the topic.

Comment: @MichaelLevy It will affect the sound, but not nearly so much (to the ear, at least) as nonlinear distortion would. It may, however, overdrive subsequent amplifiers into high-distortion modes such as clipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinusoidal functions happen to be eigenfunctions of linear, time-invariant (LTI) systems. This means that if we input a sinusoid into a LTI system, the output will be a perfect reconstruction, potentially with some amplitude change and phase shift.

HOWEVER: here is where many people get mixed up. In real life, we can never input a perfect sinusoid into a system. The reason is that a sinusoid exists for all time. If we start the input at time t=0, that implies for all t<0, the input was zero. So we instead are inputting a sinusoid multiplied by the Heaviside step function.

If you recall your Fourier transform properties, the product of two functions in time is the convolution of the Fourier transforms of those functions in the frequency domain. So if you have x(t)=sin(wt)u(t), where u(t) is the step function, then in frequency we must convolve with the Fourier transform of the step function -- which contains all frequencies.

We usually refer to the response of the system to a step input as the step response, or the transient response. And for any practical inputs to a system, you are always going to invoke these step functions, or variants of the step function, meaning you will excite all frequencies in your system.

Now to go back to your question, if you have a sharp resonance in your system, that resonance will be excited by a step input, causing ringing at the output. In an audio system, such ringing is highly undesirable, and could be perceived as "distortion," although distortion is a loaded term that can mean many different things. I'm addition, the fact that different frequencies will have different output amplitudes for given input amplitudes is likewise undesirable -- hence the existence of audio equalizers. The unequal representation of different frequencies in a signal can certainly distort the shape of the signal. For example, the Fourier transform of a square wave have a defined amplitude relationship between all the harmonics (namely, all even harmonics are zero, and the odd harmonics drop off in a sinc-like fashion). If that amplitude relationship changes, you don't have a square wave anymore, you have something else.

To go further, if we input a broadband signal input the system (for example, a pulse or rect function), then the frequency selectivity of a system with sharp resonance will distort that signal by means of aforementioned ways. You can think of a pulse as u(t)-u(t-t0), which like the simple step function, also experiences the transient response of a system, and hence the resonance.

The effects of nonflat frequency response are not unique to audio. For example, in communication systems, the channel over which signals travel from transmitter to receiver also has a frequency response. In wireless communications, you can have an effect called channel fading, whereby due to environmental reflections of the transmitted electromagnetic waves, certain bands of frequencies are attenuated more than others. As a result, any communication link that uses a bandwidth larger than the width of these bands tends to suffer severe performance degradation (due to signal distortion, intersymbol-interference, etc.), as the channel frequency response is not flat across the bandwidth of interest. So many communication channels will use a channel equalizer (very similar to an audio equalizer) to counteract the nonflat frequency response.

An effect that is not really a concern in audio however is the effect of group delay. In your plots, you only show the magnitude response of a system with resonance. What you are leaving out is the phase response, which is certainly not flat. The sharper the resonance (higher Q, smaller damping factor), the faster the phase changes near the resonance. This means that certain frequencies will be delayed more than others. The effect is most easily quantified by the change in group delay, or the derivative of phase with respect to frequency (i.e. the slope of the phase response curve). You want the group delay to be as flat as possible in most systems (not as important in audio), as it is yet another form of distortion.

These are all just different ways of looking at the same effect, but I hope they are all insightful.

Answer (score 3):

The narrow frequency response of an old AM radio or an old telephone is usually not called distortion. An amplitude-changing audio compressor circuit is usually not called distortion.

Distortion is usually called Harmonic Distortion or Intermodulation Distortion.

Resonance in an audio system usually continues for a while after the input signal has stopped, like the resonance of a poorly damped speaker that sounds like a bongo drum.

Comment: Yes, harmonic distortion is listed as a form of distortion here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion

Comment: Intermodultion distortion is also mentioned in [3]. "With respect to audio, distortion refers to any kind of deformation of an output waveform compared to its input, usually clipping, harmonic distortion, or intermodulation distortion (mixing phenomena) caused by non-linear behavior of electronic components and power supply limitations."

Answer (score 1):

> Does a resonant peak produce a distorted wave form?

That's a qualified no. A resonant peak is a property of linear systems, so *nonlinear* distortion is not implied at all.

In practice, it depends. Resonant peaks in the response of physical electronic systems can cause clipping, limiting, or otherwise operation in the nonlinear region of the system's response. And that's when distortion will occur, by definition. But if the system remains linear, then by definition there's no distortion.

It must be understood which distortion we're talking about:

- we're not talking about "different looking" input vs. output waveforms as seen on the oscilloscope, because they can look plenty different in spite of a perfectly linear system response,
- we're talking about **harmonic** or **nonlinear** distortion, where if you feed some frequency \$f_1\$ to the system, you get some of its integer multiples at the output too, and potentially also the intermodulation products if more than one input frequency is present.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking this through some more, here is my qualitative answer.

(1) Most ideal case.

In the most ideal case, one might consider a system with a flat frequency response, and whose output never saturates. In such case, regardless of the frequency spectrum of the input, or amplitude of the input, the output will be precisely linearly related to the input.

(2) Less ideal case.

In a less ideal case, one might consider a system with a frequency response that is more or less flat. We can say, for example, that for all frequencies the frequency response is continuous and the peak and trough differ by less than 3 decibels. In such case, regardless of the frequency spectrum of the input, or amplitude of the input, the output will not be precisely linearly related to the input; rather it will be slightly distorted. However, the distortion is so slight that we say that *as far as we are concerned, as a practical matter the outputs and inputs are linearly related and there is no appreciable distortion*.

(3) Non-ideal case.

In a non ideal case, one might consider a system with a frequency response that has a finite bandwidth such that for all frequencies within a continuous interval of frequencies (i.e., the passband), the frequency response differs by less than 3 decibels. In such case, (i) if the frequency spectrum of the input is strictly within the passband, the output will not be precisely linearly related to the input; rather the output will be slightly distorted, but so slight that we say that *as far as we are concerned, as a practical matter the outputs and inputs are linearly related  and there is no appreciable distortion*. Yet, (ii)  if the frequency spectrum of the input is not strictly within the passband, the output will not, as a rule, by linearly related to the input. In fact, there would be significant distortion due to, and only due to, the frequency response of the system.

(4) The question at hand.

Thus, to answer my question, we take a second look at the example provided in the figure above, which is in the original question.  In the example provided there, as $\zeta$ changes, the bandwidth changes too. In particular, as zeta decreases below 0.5 the bandwidth decreases though the center frequency remains unaltered, . Thus,  for any  fixed value of $\zeta$, the system has a frequency response with a passband characterized by a continuous interval of frequencies whose frequency response differs by less than 3 decibels. In such case, like in (3), (i) if the frequency spectrum of the input is strictly within that bandwidth, the output will **not** be precisely linearly related to the input; rather the output will be slightly distorted, but so slight that we say that *as far as we are concerned, as a practical matter the outputs and inputs are linearly related   and there is no appreciable distortion*. Yet, (ii)  if the frequency spectrum of the input is not strictly within that passband, the output will not be linearly related to the input. In fact, there would be significant distortion due to, and only due to, the frequency response of the system.

**Conclusion**

In conclusion, a system with a resonant peak does, in fact, introduce the *possibility* of distortion due to, and only due to, the frequency response of the system. However, as a rule, a band of frequencies exist such that if, only if, an input is comprised of frequencies within that band, the output will be (for all intents and purposes) linearly related to the input; thus, the input will not be appreciably distorted. On the contrary, if and input is comprised of frequencies both inside that band and outside that band, the output will, in fact, be appreciably distorted.